# VPN is overriting my default internet settings

Tags: networking, ip, vpn

When I connect to a VPN I am unable to connect to resources (Such as databases) using IP addresses that belong to my network. This is somewhat expected but is there a workaround for this ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You might have to add route policy for this.

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows you can try [Shrew Soft VPN Client](https://www.shrew.net/software),
it has a customization options to route through VPN only certain address ranges.

The main problem is that usually you can have only one DNS server (VPN's or own), so resources that are not mapped in the main DNS will only be accesible using their IP.